# How can i run this excel script on all sheets ? Remove all hyperlinks in entire workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

This is the script. It runs well on single sheet when i call via alt+8

However i want to run it in all sheets how can i do that ?

Ty very much

Here the macro

```
Sub RemoveHyperlinks()
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete
End Sub
```

Basically i want to remove all hyperlinks in entire workbook

Ty very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim w as Worksheet

For Each w in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    w.Hyperlinks.Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark it with the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop like this:

```
Sub RemoveAllHyperlinks()
Dim oSht as Object
For each oSht in Activeworkbook.sheets
oSht.Hyperlinks.Delete
next oSht
End Sub
```